# Google Places - 2 References for the same location?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, geofencing

According to my understanding of the Google Places API, one location is supposed to have 1 reference number, but doesn't seem to be the case.

```
Starbucks @ (43.844994, -79.47062699999998)
```

CnRsAAAA3j46TiVNz6Nps7nARdmH4Q1OnqmuOE6RB10Y335g45CSRYM1DwyUlPpySF0sRAzpyEwnvHGQlWDHcPsE5J6YKqPdlPeJc7v3ogCx7lNI7_4Jgyz57RWMJj82lCd1VpLLKJ5wioZjmaYHvbcL9qVlfBIQErBSC4SN-SGjRAw-cXA-FBoUBLEcJY6W06c1I7EFDZolVgUPlpo

```
Starbucks @ (43.844994, -79.47062699999998)
```

CnRsAAAAqhxrWD8ibwXPCVhNwiAnrtpJ-558_spLSvzTaJWXVlhmm6cRK9at6v_Uu_Kewp3htkg_mvxekrJcf1GEqAhckkMc0foDyJxLSqQfQuDrHRYa9qv6QMiS2rCyph4qiL0xIftTSOa0QlQ7h_RY3h2LuhIQPOaAFVblenUaaN3-EMPcXhoULAHJS2bc3tjQ-bQUvKE-ChR63zw*

Does anyone know why this might be? Both locations seem to be referenced from yellow pages, which makes this even more confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses)

reference contains a token that can be used to query the Details service in future. This token may differ from the reference used in the request to the Details service. It is recommended that stored references for Places be regularly updated. Although this token uniquely identifies the Place, the converse is not true: **a Place may have many valid reference tokens.**

Comment: Big double-doh, thanks... I wonder why they do this - I can understand if it was from multiple sources, but both of these were sources from yellowpages.com... Alas, it's easy enough to work around, but it means things like a places search within bounds, requires the extra step of deduping by search name and lat/long.  A radar search doesn't give you address etc to check, you'd have to call an extra search on the place ref, and we're already hitting google query limit quotas just with our radar searches.